# change url after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, .htaccess

I have a form with a search field as follows:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <form name="form"  method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input name="q" type="search" placeholder="Type here please" autofocus />
    <input name="Submit" value="Search" class="searchbutton" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.q.value;">
    </form>
```

It works fine, but I would like to have a more friendly URL.
When the user enters a search string, e.g. 'something', the URL looks as follows:
`http://example.com/somefolder/?q=something`.
I would like the URL look like `http://example.com/somefolder/something`.

Any idea how I should do that?

I am already using htaccess, which allows users to enter the friendly URL, but it does not keep SEO friendly URL permanently in the address field.

My htaccess looks as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /$1?q=$2 [QSA]
```

This htaccess entry works fine, but it updates the browser's address field.
So what I want now it actually the second part of the job. I want to prevent the browser from updating the URL to the original URL. htaccess only rewrites the URL the user enters to the original URL, because only this one is understandable for the server. htaccess does not permanently change the URL.

If I use for instance the following form:

```
<form class="searchbox" name="form" method="get">
<input class="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Type here please" autofocus>
<input name="Submit" value="Search" class="searchbutton" type="submit">
</form>
```

the output would be `http://example.com/somefolder/?q=something&Submit=Search`. Now I only want to get rid of `?q=`.

Comment: URL re-writing using `.htaccess`,  not JavaScript.

Comment: Use .htaccess file to rewrite the URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify url with .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408913/modify-url-with-htaccess-file)

Comment: duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408913/modify-url-with-htaccess-file

Comment: I already use htaccess. This is the second part of the task, so to speak. I want to keep the new URL in the address field. I have made some modifications of my initial question above to make it clearer.

Comment: what browsers do u use? chrome may not trigger this,I have test.

Comment: I am using Firefox. The same bahaviour on Internet Explorer. Anyway, I am obviously not the user for whom the website is meant. It shall be the same in all browser.